# c code: if do/while won't do what I ask it to do

Tags: c, facebook, if-statement, while-loop

i'm new to c coding and I have this problem to resolve:

I have to make a code that receives the notes of the students and proceed them...

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

int intra, final,tps, nbNotes=0;
float moyPond, globale;
char reponse; /* réponse de l'usager */
const float POND_INTRA = 0.30;
const float POND_FINAL = 0.40;
const float POND_TPS = 0.30;
const float POND_INTRA_FINAL = 0.70;

do
{
    printf("Entrez vos 3 notes en ordre soit intra, final et tps: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &intra, &final, &tps);
    nbNotes++;

    /* calcul de la moyenne de l'intra avec le final */
    moyPond = ((intra * POND_INTRA) + (final * POND_FINAL)) / POND_INTRA_FINAL;

    if (moyPond < 40 && tps > 50)
    {
        tps = 50;
    }
    /* calcul de la note finale */
    globale = (POND_INTRA * intra) + (POND_FINAL * final) + (POND_TPS * tps);

    printf("\nVoulez-vous entrer une autre note? (o/n) \n");
    fflush(stdin);

    reponse = getchar();
    printf("intra    final    tps     moyenne pondérée     globale     littérale\n");

} while (toupper(reponse) == 'O');

printf("%d       %d       %d     %6.2f               %6.2f", intra, final, tps, moyPond, globale);

if (globale >= 90 && globale <= 100)
{
    printf("       A+\n");
}

if (globale >= 85 && globale < 90)
{
    printf("       A\n");
}

if (globale >= 80 && globale < 85)
{
    printf("       A-\n");
}

if (globale >= 77 && globale < 80)
{
    printf("       B+\n");
}

if (globale >= 73 && globale < 77)
{
    printf("       B\n");
}

if (globale >= 70 && globale < 73)
{
    printf("       B-\n");
}

if (globale >= 65 && globale < 70)
{
    printf("       C+\n");
}

if (globale >= 60 && globale < 65)
{
    printf("       C\n");
}

if (globale >= 57 && globale < 60)
{
    printf("       C-\n");
}

if (globale >= 54 && globale < 57)
{
    printf("       D+\n");
}

if (globale >= 50 && globale < 54)
{
    printf("       D\n");
}

if (globale >= 35 && globale < 50)
{
    printf("       E\n");
}

if (globale >= 0 && globale < 35)
{
    printf("       F\n");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: What has this got to do with [tag:facebook]?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `fflush` on `stdin` is undefined behavior, in other words, you shouldn't do that. Here's the relevant quote from the C11 draft specification, emphasis added

> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fflush(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> Description
>   If stream points to an **output** stream or an **update** stream in
>   which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function
>   causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host
>   environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined**.

To fix the problem, replace these lines

```
fflush(stdin);
response = getchar();
```

with this line

```
scanf( " %c", &response );
/*      ^----- the space in front of the %c is important, 
 *             it causes scanf to skip any white space 
 */
```